# How do I see all foreign keys and primary keys in SQL Server Management System

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server Management System, how do I get a list of all foreign key constraints pointing to a particular table? a particular column? This is the same thing as this Oracle question, but for SQL Server Management System.

Also How do I see all primary keys of all tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'yourTableName'
```

Comment: yes.....actually so allows accpeting only after 11 minites......i have upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You can select the tablename in the query in management studio and press ALT+F1 then it display all keys and index on that table